# Count users of wso2 identity server

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

How can I count users of Primary user store on wso2 identity server 5.11 with default configs like user store with embedded ldap.

Comment: Count users are only supported for `JDBCUserStores` because doing this for `LDAPUserStores` will cause a huge hit on performance. https://github.com/wso2/docs-is/issues/1495

Comment: I handle it with SCIM :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also count the users via management console or admin services. By default JDBC user store supports this service.
Please refer https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/develop/counting-users-and-roles-using-management-console-and-admin-services/ for more information.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).